# why is my cross validation matrix returning nan sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, cross-validation

I'm trying to do cross validation (specfically LOOCV) on a simple linear regression model, but for some reason when calculating the score of the process im getting `nan` for all the entries. Does anyone know why?

Here is the code:

```
#use sklearn
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
#now using sklearn repeat linear regression with sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()

X = np.array(auto['horsepower']).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array(auto['mpg']).reshape(-1,1)

cv = model_selection.cross_val_score(lr,X,y,cv=len(X))
```

Here is the data:

```
mpg cylinders   displacement    horsepower  weight  acceleration    year    origin  name
0   18.0    8   307.0   130 3504    12.0    70  1   chevrolet chevelle malibu
1   15.0    8   350.0   165 3693    11.5    70  1   buick skylark 320
2   18.0    8   318.0   150 3436    11.0    70  1   plymouth satellite
3   16.0    8   304.0   150 3433    12.0    70  1   amc rebel sst
4   17.0    8   302.0   140 3449    10.5    70  1   ford torino
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
387 27.0    4   140.0   86  2790    15.6    82  1   ford mustang gl
388 44.0    4   97.0    52  2130    24.6    82  2   vw pickup
389 32.0    4   135.0   84  2295    11.6    82  1   dodge rampage
390 28.0    4   120.0   79  2625    18.6    82  1   ford ranger
391 31.0    4   119.0   82  2720    19.4    82  1   chevy s-10
392 rows × 9 columns



<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 392 entries, 0 to 391
Data columns (total 9 columns):
mpg             392 non-null float64
cylinders       392 non-null int64
displacement    392 non-null float64
horsepower      392 non-null int64
weight          392 non-null int64
acceleration    392 non-null float64
year            392 non-null int64
origin          392 non-null int64
name            392 non-null object
dtypes: float64(3), int64(5), object(1)
memory usage: 27.7+ KB
```

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the vignette of [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html):

> scoring: string, callable, list/tuple, dict or None, default: None
>   [....] If None, the estimator’s score method is used.

For `LinearRegression()` this is the R^2 of the prediction. But R^2 doesn't make sense when n=1. Try something like the mean squared error, below I used `'neg_mean_squared_error'` which is the negative of MSE, available from `sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

auto = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data",
                 delimiter=r"\s+",header=None,
                 names=["mpg","cylinders","displacement","horsepower","weight",
                        "acceleration","model year","origin","car name"],
                   na_values=['?'])

lr = LinearRegression()
X = np.array(auto['horsepower']).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array(auto['mpg']).reshape(-1,1)

model_selection.cross_val_score(lr,X,y,cv=len(X),scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: when you say n=1, do you mean 1 predictor variable?

Comment: in LOOCV, you leave one observation out, fit the model using the rest and predict on this one observation, hence n=1

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#Leave-one-out_cross-validation

Comment: i was aware of that, but didnt realise the n referred to the size of the testing set. I thought it referred to the total number of data points, regardless of whether they were in the training or test set. Thanks for clarifying